# Recommend a Linux FTP server for customers and internal use?

Tags: linux, ftp

We currently use a BulletProof FTP server on Windows.  While it works well enough I have no real need to have an FTP server running on a Windows platform that I have to patch/secure, etc.

What I would REALLY like is an FTP server running under a VMWARE appliance...but I'll settle for just a great FTP server that is easy to configure with a decent GUI interface for administration.

**REQUIREMENTS:**

- Linux based
- Runs under VMWARE
- GUI interface for administration
- Easy setup for users (new users, passwords, etc.)
- Easy folder setup with automatic permissions
- Expiring accounts/one-time use accounts

**NICE THINGS TO HAVE:**

- AD Integration in addition to local accounts
- GUI interface for clients (web interface)
- Automatic email notification to clients with username/password
- SFTP (secure/SSL)
- Administrative notifications (login reports, disk usage, etc.)

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that you are after a web interface more than en FTP Server. *nix philosophy is do one thing and do it right. FTP servers just serve content. You should try something like cpanel to setup all the other things that you look for. In most cases you can setup pam to authenticate users to your AD, hence auth your FTP users. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why don't you use the SFTP server of the OpenSSH daemon?

Comment: I want ONLY an FTP server.  This is for customers of ours to FTP us files and for us to place files in their "buckets" for them to grab.  I don't really need cpanel, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one I really like.  Wasn't free but we love it.  www.wftpserver.com

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree w/Torian; your best bet is likely cpanel.  However, it really isn't that hard to do it w/out a gui.  There are plenty of good tutorials out there:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=518293

Comment: The GUI requirement is so that our helpdesk can provision an FTP user and their folders without needing much of a tutorial.  Something with a webadmin style interface would be ideal.

Comment: Maybe this will help. http://www.howtoforge.com/installing_webmin_ubuntu_feisty

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this: a free, downloadable, lightweight Linux VMware image that can be used to create an SFTP server with GUI configuration tools (including Webmin to configure users).

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/fileserver